# displaying last-name that ends with n in Unix

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, terminal

good evening
i have the following code that i need to extract only the last-names that end with n

i appreciate your assistance

i have already tried

```
sort brokers.dat [^.*\n]

sort brokers.dat ^.*\n

sort -nr -t":" -k2 brokers.dat
```

none worked

```
id first-name last-name
9:Danielle:Perety
8:Andre:Sinclair
7:John:Bush
6:Ted:Gore
5:Elric:Crofton
4:Frank:Denzel
3:Richard:Bradley
2:Herbert:Jackson
1:John:Smith
15:Frederick:Raven
14:Tommy:Mack
13:Bruce:Smith
12:Andrew:Wallace
11:Parker:Hamilton
```

Comment: Do you want to sort or only filter out lines ending with 'n' ? To filter lines matching a pattern, you can use "grep".

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the question

thanks

```
sort brokers.dat -R | grep '\n$'
```